# Symfony2 get validation message

Tags: symfony

I have a few validation messages in the file `validators.en.yml`:

```
soporte.nombre.not_blank: The name cannot be empty
soporte.price.is_integer: The price should be integer
soporte.not_repeat: soporte cannot be repeat
```

I valid making a query to the database:

```
$validarPorNombreAndTipo = $this->crud->findOneBy(
    $soporte, array('nombre' => $soporte->getNombre(),                  
                    'tipo' => $object->tipo
    )
);
if ($validarPorNombreAndTipo){
         $error= //here i need to get soporte.not_repeat that is on file validators.en.yml;
        }
```

excuse me for my bad English, I used the translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the translation, this code should work :

```
$validarPorNombreAndTipo = $this->crud->findOneBy(
$soporte, array('nombre' => $soporte->getNombre(),                  
                'tipo' => $object->tipo
    )
);

if ($validarPorNombreAndTipo){
    $error= $this->get('translator')->trans('soporte.not_repeat', array(), 'validators');
    // Third param is the translation domain (first part of the translation file)
}
```

However, i suggest you to read this : http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

If you want to follow Symfony best practices, you should create a custom constraint class/Validator and move your validation logic into it.

Best regards